# Writing a dictionary of Spark data frames to S3 bucket

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark

Suppose we have a dictionary of PySpark dataframes. Is there a way to write this dictionary to an S3 bucket? The purpose of this is to read these PySpark data frames and then convert them into pandas data frames. Below is some code and the errors I get:

```
columns = ["language","users_count"]
data = [("Java", "20000"), ("Python", "100000"), ("Scala", "3000")]

#spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('SparkByExamples.com').getOrCreate()
rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data)


df1 = rdd.toDF()
df1.printSchema()

columns = ["language","users_count"]
data = [("C", "2000"), ("Java", "10000"), ("Lisp", "300")]

#spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('SparkByExamples.com').getOrCreate()
rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data)


df2 = rdd.toDF()
df2.printSchema()

spark_dict = {df1: '1', df2: '2'}


import boto3
import pickle
s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket='test'
key='pickle_list.pkl'
pickle_byte_obj = pickle.dumps(spark_dict)
try:
    s3_resource.Object(bucket,key).put(Body=pickle_byte_obj)
except:
    print("Error in writing to S3 bucket")
```

with this error:

```
An error was encountered:
can't pickle _thread.RLock objects
Traceback (most recent call last):
TypeError: can't pickle _thread.RLock objects
```

Also tried dumping the dictionary of PySpark data frames to a json file:

```
import json
flatten_dfs_json = json.dumps(spark_dict)
```

and got this error:

An error was encountered:
Object of type DataFrame is not JSON serializable

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 231, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/json/encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/json/encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/json/encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type DataFrame is not JSON serializable
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Suppose we have a dictionary of PySpark dataframes. Is there a way to write this dictionary to an S3 bucket?

Yes (you might need to configure access key and secret key)

```py
df.write.format('json').save('s3a://bucket-name/path')
```

> The purpose of this is to read these PySpark data frames and then convert them into pandas data frames.

My 2 cents: This sounds wrong to me, you don't have to convert data to Pandas, that defeats the purpose of using Spark at the first place.

Comment: I want to use pandas functionality in a Spark data frame.

Comment: Most Pandas tasks can be done with Spark, either with native Spark API or with UDF. The idea is trying to use Spark transformation API as much as you can instead if converting it to Pandas.